# Missing something obvious and CSS is not getting rendered properly

Tags: html, css, markup, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, I tried making a simple HTML using [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) but something is broken *on my side* and I am unable to figure out what is wrong. I put up a jsFiddle page is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrczj/3/) and have attached a screenshot as well. The problems are:

- Text box styles are not as shown on the Bootstrap page
- Labels and Textboxes are not getting aligned (labels on left, textbox on right)
- There is no spacing between fields
- The drop down box does not work.
- The search box is messed up

I don't seem top understand what step I am missing. It is pretty late in here and I might use another set of eyes. Can someone please tell me if I am missing something obvious? The buttons get style so I am not really sure what is happening.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a little bit of CSS.

Floating the input and the label to the left and then adding a bit of margin.

```
label,input
{
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
label{
    clear:left;
    width:50px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrczj/1/

Also note that this portion is invalid HTML:

```
<input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox">Enable tooltip </input>
```

You just need to make the text into a label like you have with the other text fields. The input has no closing tag in HTML.

**UPDATE**

After a closer look at your HTML it looks like you forgot to put your form fields in a form.

Inputs always need to go inside a `<form>[...]</form>`.

Here's your code again with the form tags included: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrczj/2/

Comment: +1 Thank You. Honestly speaking, I wasn't aware that we need to add our own CSS to make it look like the ones on the Bootstrap page. So does that mean, I need to add my own shadow effects to imitate the textbox look? And the dropdown? Sorry! I'm just a little confused as I thought this is built-into Bootstrap.

Comment: Perhaps you don't. I'm not familiar with twitter bootstrap but I'll have a quick look now.

Comment: Oh boy! This is embarrassing! I'm going home and getting some sleep! Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: These things happen to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle doesn't really look like your screenshot for me?
I had a look at your markup and found a mistake:

```
<input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox">Enable tooltip </input>
```

You can't put text into an input like that. You need to change it to:

```
<input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox" />Enable tooltip
```

or:

```
<input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox"><label>Enable tooltip</label>
```

Comment: +1 Good catch! I updated my question with this part fixed. And yes, the inconsistency... I just noticed it! I must've updated my code after taking a screenshot.